# Ad revenues via Google cache

Tags: advertising, cache

Do ad revenues from page-views (as opposed to ad-clicks) accrue from webpages viewed via Google cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran a test using http://www.cachedpages.com/ on a blog using ad sense. The Google cached page does not load ads. In this case, the answer to your question would be no.

However, I ran the same test with another site using a different ad network, and the ads were loaded. So in this case, the answer to your question is yes.

Conclusion: it depends of the ad network.

Comment: Thanks. FWIW I've found if you search for `http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:{INSERT URL HERE}&strip=1` you'll get a text-only version which presumably won't pay ads.  Dropping `&strip=1` returns full cached version. And you can sub `%s` for the url and add to Chrome as a custom search engine.

Comment: Don't forget to approve the answer if it answers your question. Cheers!